# How to manage two django versions in single ubuntu machine

Tags: python, django

How to install two different versions of django. I went through many answer but none of them satisfying my need.

1.I want two install 1.5 or 1.6 without replacing 1.4

2.My application is currently live which was developed using 1.4.

3.But I want to use some python-django libraries to get new features in my application.

4.That library is compatible with django 1.5+.

5.I dont want to use virtual environment.

6.And I want to install in same directory/dist-packeges.

Is there any way two do so,,,,,,?

Comment: What's the issue with virtual environments?

Comment: I said I don't want to use virtualenv

Comment: because my application is in production and I want two version two use for same project. As I said project requires 1.4 and new APIs that I want to use for same project have dependencies on djnago 1.5+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two versions in the same project. That's impossible: they would simply conflict - for example, what would happen when you did `from django import template`? How would the system know which version to use?

The only thing you could possibly do is have two separate projects, with their own versions of Django (and yes, using virtualenvs), each serving a part of the site.

Otherwise you will simply need to upgrade your existing project to Django 1.5+. It's not hard, Django is very good with backwards compatibility.

Comment: Hi Daniel Roseman, I think backwards compatibility is not good from 1.6 to 1.4 and if I upgrade its replacing the current 1.4....

Comment: Yes, but that is what you will have to do. And the main incompatibility is the removal of the old function-based generic views, if you're not using those you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanx, Its making sense and seems will help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Django code is open to you So I will suggest to customize your current Django code with any library you want.
2. Or Create new app as utils and override current django feature into this new app and use this app as a django plugin.